# swift - how to force the app to show a particular view after return from background

Tags: ios, swift

Ok, i know that when applicationWillEnterForeground fires from my AppDelegate that I can trigger events. What I would like to do is force the app to show a certain view when It re-appears from the background. The view is a UIViewController called loginViewController and it has a storyboard Id of "initViewController"
My question is, what do I use in this function (applicationWillEnterForground) to make this view load when the app comes into focus again?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never done this, but you can probably accomplish it by adding the UIViewController to the UIViewController stack, if you just want to add a view controller and show its view **(see Case 1)** or by replacing the root view controller, if you want to discard the existing view controller stack and use a new one **(see Case 2)**

**Case 1)** In the first case you need a reference to the UIViewController that you want to make its parent view controller. You can save this in a static variable somewhere or if you are just planning on showing a temporary view when the app restarts then you can get a reference to the root view controller use it as the parent:

```
// get a reference to the main storyboard
let mainSB = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

// get a reference to the root view controller
if let rootVC = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController,

    // get a reference to the view controller using identifier
    initVC = mainSB.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("initViewController") as? UIViewController {

        // present the view controller 
        rootVC.presentViewController(initVC, animated: false, completion: nil)

}
```

When you are finished use logic from within the view controller to dismiss it, and your user should be back where they started:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

**Case 2)** You can discard the existing view controller stack and start a new one by replacing the root view controller and building up the stack manually. Present the view controllers in order with animated parameter set to false.

```
// get a reference to the main storyboard
let mainSB = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

// get references to view controllers
if let vc1 = mainSB.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vc1") as? UIViewController,
    vc2 = mainSB.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vc2") as? UIViewController {

        // set root view controller
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController = vc1

        // build up the view controller stack by adding next vc
        vc1.presentViewController(vc2, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

**Navigation Controllers**

If one of your view controllers is a navigation controller you will need to cast it as such, and then push any view controllers onto your navigation controller. Navigation controllers have their own stack.

```
if let myNavCon = mainSB.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("nav") as? UINavigationController {

    // push view controller onto navigation controller stack
    myNavCon.pushViewController(someViewController, animated: false )
}
```

**WARNING**

This does not deal with the model of your app at all (only the UI). You will also need to set any data that you would have set in prepareForSegue, etc. An easy system to use when you have VCs you present  both programmatically and via storyboard segues is to take the code that would have been in prepare for segue and move it to your own instance method that takes a reference to the child view controller as its parameter. Then you can call it from prepare to segue with the destination view controller or from code before you present the view controller.

**None of this code has been tested. It was written directly via the website. It likely contains typos.** Please let me know so I can fix any.

Comment: You cannot imagine how much this answer has helped me to understand the structure of the storyboard and it's UI elements. Your answer worked, and i am very grateful !